# Use a surface fit object from matlab in simulink

Tags: simulink

I performed a surface fit of some data in Matlab using the fit function.
To be more specific:

```
func_trim= fit( [hopper_volume, water_ballast_volume], trim, 'poly55');
```

It returned a multi-variable polynomial:

```
 Linear model Poly55:
 func_trim(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p30*x^3 
                + p21*x^2*y + p12*x*y^2 + p03*y^3 + p40*x^4 + p31*x^3*y 
                + p22*x^2*y^2 + p13*x*y^3 + p04*y^4 + p50*x^5 + p41*x^4*y 
                + p32*x^3*y^2 + p23*x^2*y^3 + p14*x*y^4 + p05*y^5
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   p00 =      -4.742  (-4.745, -4.74)
   p10 =   5.068e-05  (4.969e-05, 5.167e-05)
   p01 =    0.001447  (0.001436, 0.001459)
   p20 =  -3.565e-09  (-3.731e-09, -3.399e-09)
   p11 =  -6.534e-08  (-6.7e-08, -6.369e-08)
   p02 =    -1.6e-07  (-1.815e-07, -1.385e-07)
   p30 =   5.919e-13  (5.795e-13, 6.043e-13)
   p21 =   4.683e-12  (4.552e-12, 4.815e-12)
   p12 =   1.129e-11  (9.908e-12, 1.267e-11)
   p03 =   1.471e-10  (1.282e-10, 1.659e-10)
   p40 =  -2.017e-17  (-2.059e-17, -1.975e-17)
   p31 =  -1.562e-16  (-1.611e-16, -1.513e-16)
   p22 =   -6.93e-16  (-7.444e-16, -6.417e-16)
   p13 =  -9.909e-16  (-1.551e-15, -4.308e-16)
   p04 =  -6.751e-14  (-7.516e-14, -5.986e-14)
   p50 =   2.446e-22  (2.392e-22, 2.5e-22)
   p41 =   2.186e-21  (2.118e-21, 2.254e-21)
   p32 =   1.321e-20  (1.243e-20, 1.4e-20)
   p23 =   3.805e-20  (2.969e-20, 4.642e-20)
   p14 =   2.262e-20  (-6.978e-20, 1.15e-19)
   p05 =   1.059e-17  (9.424e-18, 1.175e-17)
```

I now want to use this object in the simulink environment.
One option would be to explicitly define this in simulink by just hard-coding it in. However I don't prefer this because the coefficients might change (quite frequently) over time and I would have to repeat this every time.

So in short. Are there any more elegant ways to use this object straight in simulink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to wrap the fit object into a function handle and then call that from an [Interpreted MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/interpretedmatlabfunction.html) block.

To create the function handle:

```
>> myFunc = @(u)feval(func_trim,u);
```

Then with the Interpreted MATLAB function block you'll need to

1. Mux the x and y signals together, then feed the combined signal into the block.
2. Use "myFunc(u)" - without the double quotes - as the name of the function to call.

The above is not the fastest approach from an execution pespective, nor will it allow for code generation, but it is by far the easiest/quickest to get something up an running.

Comment: I don't know why on Earth this was so complicated to get right. This was the only answer I found on this seemingly important feature.

For other people who after reading this answer still could not solve it, try using "myFunc([u(1), u(2)])" instead of "myFunc(u)" when including the function name.

I'm not sure what configuration I have that makes this different than what the OP has, but this worked for me.